# How to use a Schema.SObjectType as a variable to instantiate a set?

Tags: apex, schema

I am trying to create a class that can take in multiple different objects(one at a time), and work from there with the data it is passed in.

Code is as follows:

```
public static void createCharges(List<SObject> sObjsWithChargesList) {
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeNameType = sObjsWithChargesList.getSObjectType();
        String SObjectTypeName = String.valueOf(SObjectTypeNameType);
        Set<SObjectTypeName> sObjSet = new Set<SObjectTypeName>();
        for(SObjectTypeName sObj : sObjsWithChargesList){
            //Do things
        }
 }
```

The error I am getting is "Invalid type: SObjectTypeName"

Is there a way I can pull off what I am attempting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a variable; it has to be a concrete type at compile time.

That said, you can probably just use sObject as the type:

```
        Set<sObject> sObjSet = new Set<sObject>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should carefully inspect your use case and see if `Set` is the appropriate data structure. If you must use it, you are going to have a much harder time making your code dynamic, because for example this code will never work:

```
Set<SObject> records = new Set<Account>();
```

Generics with `Set` are broken. However, if `List` will work, the following should help. If you must use `Set`, it will have to just be a generic `Set<SObject>`, not a concretely typed version (e.g. `Set<Account>`).

---

You can get the name of your collection type by constructing it like so:

```
String collectionTypeName = 'List<' + sObjectTypeName + '>';
```

Then, you can use `Type.forName` to get the actual type:

```
Type collectionType = Type.forName(collectionTypeName);
```

Then, you can simply invoke `newInstance`:

```
List<SObject> collection = (List<SObject>)collectionType.newInstance();
```

Comment: Note that the OP is getting the type from the collection, not the collection's content, so you don't need the collectionTypeName and collectionType values in your example, above. Just use the collection type already obtained, yes?

Comment: Pretty difficult to ascertain what OP actually hopes to accomplish.

Comment: `List<sObject> collection = Type.forName('List<Account>').newInstance();` is throwing error - **Illegal assignment from Object to List<SObject>**. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @salesforce-sas You need to cast the result. Updated my answer.